# ¿Por qué fetch no obtiene respuesta?

Tags: php, javascript

Estoy intentando resolver un autocompletado en un input de mi formulario. Utilizando banderas me doy cuenta que el código llega hasta el `fetch` y de ahí no avanza más y ya no se que más probar....

El código es bastante simple y esta todo dentro de la misma carpeta para evitar problemas de direccionamiento, de todas formas como estoy trabajando con define porque tengo todo armado dentro de un framework...

Tampoco tira un error explicito como para poder encontrar la falla, solo se que cuando pongo un `alert` antes del `fech` se ejecuta, pero lo que ponga después del `fetch` no.

**Formulario**

```
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<? echo BASE_AWESOMPLETE?>">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<? echoTHEME_AWESOMPLETE?>">
    </head>
    <body>
    <br> 
    <div>
    <br>         
        <form action="<?php echo FRONT_ROOT.'Pago/agregarPago' ?>" method="post">
         <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body uk-margin uk-margin-medium-left uk-margin-medium-right">
          <h2>Agregar Pago</h2>
          <input type="text" id="nombre_usuario" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Escribe un nombre">
          <script src="<?php echo JS_AWESOMPLETE ?>"></script>
        <script src=" <?php echo JS_AUTOCOMPLETADO ?>"></script>
        </div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
    const $inputNombre = document.querySelector("#nombre_usuario");

    let ac = new Awesomplete($inputNombre, {
        
        list: [], // Por defecto es una lista vacía, hasta que se comienza a escribir
        minChars: 1, // Cuántos caracteres escribir para autocompletar
       
    });
    
    // Esta función filtra los datos y refresca el autocompletado
    const refrescarLista = () => {
        let valorDelInput = $inputNombre.value;
      
        if (!valorDelInput) return; // Detener si no hay valor
        alert(valorDelInput);
        // Buscar nombres de la base de datos con PHP
        //aca es en el ultimo lugar donde me anda un alert...
        fetch("./auxiliar.php?busqueda=" + valorDelInput)
            .then(r => r.json())
            .then(usuarios => { 
                // Mapeamos, ya que se requiere label y value
                ac.list = usuarios.map(usuario => ({
                    label: usuario.nombre_usuario, // Lo que aparece al buscar
                    value: usuario.id, // El valor que se pone en el input
                }));
            });
            
    };
    // Agregar un listener para cuando se cambie el contenido; en el mismo se refresca la lista
    $inputNombre.addEventListener("input", () => {
        refrescarLista();
    });

    $inputNombre.addEventListener("awesomplete-selectcomplete", function() {
        console.log("Se ha seleccionado un elemento de la lista");
    });

});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
// Si no hay búsqueda, mostrar un arreglo vacío y salir
if (empty($_GET["busqueda"])) {
    echo "[]";
    exit;
}
$bd = include_once "bd.php";
$busqueda = $_GET["busqueda"];

$sentencia = $bd->prepare("select * from usuarios where nombre_usuario like ?");
$sentencia->execute(["%$busqueda%"]);
$usuarios = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
echo json_encode($usuarios);

?>
```

Comment: y cual es el problema??? error o que sucede ???

Comment: Dentro de `usuarios.map()` estás usando la variable `usuarios`, que es un arreglo de objetos; deberías usar `usuario`, que corresponde al elemento actual.

Comment: El problema es que llega al fetch (lo sé porque probé hasta donde llega con los alerts) y no hace más nada, no hay error ni nada, simplemente no hace nada, voy a probar lo de "usuario" y te digo

Comment: @Triby Probé lo de cambiar "usaurios" por "usuario" tampoco es la solución. Tengo un alert en el primer src de script que se ejecuta perfecto seguido de un alert al inicio de script JS_AUTOCOMPLETADO que tambien se ejecuta, pero una vez que llega al fetch no hace más nada, por las dudas dejo el codigo del archivo que llama fetch.

Comment: @Triby Agregué el codigo de auxiliar.php a la publicación.

Comment: Estás haciendo un `.json()` tienes que añadir un encabezado a tu PHP: `header("Content-Type: application/json");` en la primera línea del código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo tratar de evitar cualquier posibilidad de error y, en su defecto, tener la oportunidad de capturarlo.

En PHP:

- Asegúrate de recibir un valor adecuado y eliminar espacios alrededor, por ejemplo **" mi nombre "** debe quedar como **"mi nombre"**
- Crea una variable para almacenar los valores a devolver y siempre envíala con `json_encode()`
- Evita la etiqueta de cierre final `?>`, porque accidentalmente podrías incluir caracteres posteriores (como espacios, saltos de línea u otros) que impidan que Javascript interprete la salida como JSON. En su lugar, agrega un comentario para indicar final de archivo y saber que no lo dejaste incompleto

```
<?php
// Usar asignación ternaria y trim() para eliminar espacios alrededor
$busqueda = (isset($_GET["busqueda"])) ? trim($_GET["busqueda"]) : '';
// Inicializar salida
$usuarios = [];
// Solo si hay algo que buscar
if(!empty($busqueda)) {
    $bd = include_once "bd.php";
    // Obtener solo los campos que necesitas
    $sentencia = $bd->prepare("SELECT id, nombre_usuario FROM usuarios WHERE nombre_usuario LIKE ?");
    $sentencia->execute(["%$busqueda%"]);
    $usuarios = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
// Enviar la salida
echo json_encode($usuarios);

// No usar etiqueta de cierre de PHP
// Fin de archivo
```

En Javscript:

- También elimina espacios alrededor del valor y codifica para poder enviarlo por URL (método GET) con [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/encodeURIComponent)
- No es estrictamente necesario, pero conviene limpiar la lista antes de realizar la búsqueda
- Antes de interpretar la respuesta como JSON, analiza si se ejecutó correctamente (propiedad `ok`). En [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch) hay más ejemplos
- Si algo falló, lanza un error, que vas a capturar posteriormente
- Después del segundo `.then()`, agrega `.catch()` para capturar cualquier error y mostrarlo en consola

```
const refrescarLista = () => {
    // También elimina posibles espacios alrededor del valor
    let valorDelInput = $inputNombre.value.trim();

    if(valorDelInput == '') {
        // Detener si no hay valor
        return;
    }

    alert(valorDelInput);
    // Limpia la lista, por si hay valores previos
    ac.list = [];
    // Buscar nombres de la base de datos con PHP
    fetch("./auxiliar.php?busqueda=" + encodeURIComponent(valorDelInput))
        .then(r => {
             // Solo si la respuesta tuvo éxito
             if(r.ok) {
                 // Interpretar como JSON y devolver
                 return r.json();
             }
             // Guardar mensaje de error
             let error = r.statusText;
             // Ver lo que realmente se recibió
             console.log(r.text());
             // Lanzar error, que será capturado en .catch, el siguiente .then() no se ejecutará
             throw 'Error en respuesta: ' + error;
        })
        .then(usuarios => {
            // Mapeamos, ya que se requiere label y value
            ac.list = usuarios.map(usuario => ({
                label: usuario.nombre_usuario, // Lo que aparece al buscar
                value: usuario.id, // El valor que se pone en el input
            });
        })
        // Captura cualquier posible error
        .catch(error => console.log('Error en petición: ' + error));
};
```

Con estos cambios ya debería funcionar correctamente, de lo contrario, revisa la consola del navegador y ahí verás qué es lo que está pasando.

Como última sugerencia, usa la consola en lugar de alertas para depurar, es mucho más rápido (no tienes que dar clic para cerrar) y puedes mostrar más información.

Comment: Disculpa haha me equivoqué de respuesta

Comment: muchisimas gracias!